# Bind 2 External Content Types (2 tables in SQL database) to 2 drop down lists and have 1 update the contents of the other?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, content, sql

I have 2 tables in my database called "Meetings" and "Items", items belong to a meeting.

I've created the external content types with sharepoint designer and bound them to drop down lists ("Meetings" and "Items"), When a meeting is selected I need to show the items for that meeting in the Items drop down.

I tried to use InfoPath to wire up the connection but I get "The following fields in the Sharepoint List are not supported because of their datatype and will not be available" and it shows my 2 external types.

Has anyone done anything similar?

Comment: Have you made External Lists from External Content Types? AFAIK, consuming them in InfoPath is easy... where are you getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

InfoPath forms on external lists do not support additional data sources, so you can't have more than one ECT in your form if the form is for one of the external lists.